# Delete data from table, which may not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a scenario where I have to delete records from a table, that may or may not exist in a different database. For example, the table is called Md5SumJob. Which exists in database A but not database B. So what I already have in place is a check to see if the table exists or not in the database.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'Md5SumJob')
```

But now I need to figure out how to delete the actual data in the table. The table that may or may not exist only has 1 column (nvarchar). So this is where I cannot figure out how to delete the record based on that 1 column and if the table exists or not. This is what i have tried so far but does not work:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'Md5SumJob')
        DELETE FROM x FROM (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i where i.TABLE_NAME = 'Md5SumJob') x
        JOIN @pid p on p.CtpJobId = (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i 
        where i.COLUMN_NAME = 'CtpJobId' and i.TABLE_NAME = 'Md5SumJob')
```

Comment: youll need dynamic sql. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: could you wrap the command in a TRY.... CATCH?  Then if the table isn't there, it'll just catch the error

Answer (score 2):

Use sp_executesql to execute a dynamic query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'Md5SumJob')
    EXEC sp_executesql ('DELETE From Md5SumJob');
```

Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

It is tempting to use dynamic SQL:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'Md5SumJob')
BEGIN
    exec sp_executesql 'delete from Md5SumJob where CtpJobId in (select CtpJobId from @pid)'
END;
```

The one caveat is that table variables are not scoped in the `exec`.  So, replace it with a temporary table and use:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'Md5SumJob')
BEGIN
    exec sp_executesql 'delete from Md5SumJob where CtpJobId in (select CtpJobId from #pid)'
END;
```